# get certain files from a path using swift

Tags: swift2

I have this code which prints out all files and directories for a given path. After reading the docs, I still need help to get my head around how to print out only files that do not end with .png

```
import Foundation
let filemanager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath("/Users/empl1/Desktop/myApp2")
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
    print(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [String API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:SS) documentation. You need to check if the string ends with the PNG file extension.

I've reformatted your code a little and got rid of manually going over the enumerator:

```
import Foundation
let filemanager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath("/Users/empl1/Desktop/myApp2")

if files == nil {
    print ("Could not get enumerator")
    exit(-1)
}

for file in files! {
    // check for extension is done here
    if file.hasSuffix(".png") {
        continue
    }

    print(file)
}
```